# React: How do you make a function fkeep firing while a condition/state is false? (zipcode doesn't exist inside a state) w/o causing infinte loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a input component which allows the user to enter a five digit zipcode and a dropdown which allows the user to choose one of the 50 states in the U.S.

Essentially I have a function which fires a prompt if the zipcode doesn't exist in the active state in the dropdown.

Example `90210` doesn't exist in New York, So you'll get the prompt.

Considering these components are on a page i'd like to prevent the use from leaving before correcting the error. So you get the prompt and barred from moving away until it's fixed.

My problem is once the flag `isZipInState` is `false` because the API checked the zip is not in the state and you haven't corrected the dropdown,  the useEffect can't run again as the dependency has not updated.

These are my useEffects:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (changeTabs && isZipInState) {
    setInnerActiveIndex(innerDestinationTabPosition);
    setChangeTabs(false);
  } else {
    handleZipCode();
  }
}, [changeTabs]);
```

This is my `handleZipCode` function:

```
const handleZipCode: (
  e?: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement, Element>,
  quoteRptVehicle?: QuoteVehicleScheduleRptModel,
  isStateDropDownChanged?: boolean
) => Promise<void> = async (
  e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement, Element>,
  quoteRptVehicle: QuoteVehicleScheduleRptModel,
  isStateDropDownChanged: boolean
) => {
  if (e?.target?.value?.length === 5 && isZipInFocus) {
    const response: IZipDetails = await ExternalServiceAPIService.getZipDetails(
      e.target.value.substring(0, 5)
    );
    try {
      if (
        response.places.some(
          (zipDetails) =>
            zipDetails["state abbreviation"] ===
            stateInputRef.current.props.value
        )
      ) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define
        onVehicleChange(
          {
            target: {
              name: "garagingStateCode",
              value: response.places[0]["state abbreviation"].toUpperCase(),
            },
          },
          quoteRptVehicle
        );
        setIsZipInState(true);
        setChangeTabs(true);
        setChangeSteps(true);
        setIsZipInFocus(false);
      } else {
        throw new Error();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      notify({
        toastMessage: {
          severity: "error",
          detail: "Please enter a zip that matches your state selected.",
        },
      });

      setIsZipInState(false);
      setIsZipInFocus(false);
      return;
    }
  }

  if (isStateDropDownChanged && isDropdownInFocus) {
    const response: IZipDetails = await ExternalServiceAPIService.getZipDetails(
      zipInputRef.current.props.value
    );
    try {
      if (
        response.places.some(
          (zipDetails) =>
            zipDetails["state abbreviation"] ===
            stateInputRef.current.props.value
        )
      ) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define
        onVehicleChange(
          {
            target: {
              name: "garagingStateCode",
              value: response.places[0]["state abbreviation"].toUpperCase(),
            },
          },
          quoteRptVehicle
        );
        setIsZipInState(true);
        setChangeTabs(true);
        setChangeSteps(true);
        setIsDropdownInFocus(false);
      } else {
        throw new Error();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      notify({
        toastMessage: {
          severity: "error",
          detail: "Please enter a zip that matches your state selected.",
        },
      });

      setIsZipInState(false);
      setIsDropdownInFocus(false);
      return;
    }
  }

  if (
    !isZipInFocus &&
    !isDropdownInFocus &&
    zipInputRef.current?.props?.value !== undefined
  ) {
    const response: IZipDetails = await ExternalServiceAPIService.getZipDetails(
      zipInputRef.current?.props?.value
    );

    try {
      if (
        response.places.some(
          (zipDetails) =>
            zipDetails["state abbreviation"] !==
            stateInputRef.current?.props?.value
        )
      ) {
        throw new Error();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      notify({
        toastMessage: {
          severity: "error",
          detail: "Please enter a zip that matches your state selected.",
        },
      });

      setIsZipInState(false);
    }
  }
};
```

Any help would be be appreciated!